# Making Source Code Copyable with listings

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm using listings to display some matlab code in my latex document but i'd like to have syntax highlighting. I've tried two ways of getting syntax highlighting and neither make the code copyable. The first is:

```
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
 \definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
 \lstset{
         backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
         tabsize=4,
         rulecolor=,
         language=matlab,
         basicstyle=\scriptsize,
         upquote=true,
         aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
         columns=fixed,
         showstringspaces=false,
         extendedchars=true,
         breaklines=true,
         prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
         frame=single,
         showtabs=false,
         showspaces=false,
         showstringspaces=false,
         identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
         keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
         commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
         stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
 }
```

The other way is:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{ideablue}{RGB}{1,24,146}

\lstset{ %
  language=matlab,                % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,           % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line 
                              % will be numbered
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % choose the background color. You must add         \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with     \lstinputlisting;
                              % also try caption instead of title
  keywordstyle=\color{ideablue},          % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},       % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},         % string literal style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  morekeywords={*,...},              % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  deletekeywords={...}              % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
}
```

But neither of these make the code copyable. So what can I do so that the source code is copyable?

Comment: Maybe this link could help: http://www.monperrus.net/martin/copy-pastable-listings-in-pdf-from-latex

Comment: try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble

Comment: For large code snippets, copy pasting is always a pain. Another option is to also attach the file in the PDF (I use a setup that does this automatically with `vim` module in  ConTeXt; something similar should be possible in LaTeX with the hyperref package).

Comment: Is my answer at this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108118/typesetting-an-interactive-screen-session/112160#112160 at all related to what you are trying to do?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).